# Eclipse Neon for Eclipse Committers can't resolve org.eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I recently upgraded to Eclipse Neon.  I had a plugin project that built fine in Eclipse Luna, but now in neon, everywhere that I imported "org.eclipse."something I get an error:

```
 The import org.eclipse cannot be resolved.
```

The plugin.xml has errors etc.
The Project build path has "Plugin Dependencies" on the build path.

My version of Eclipse is
Eclipse IDE for Eclipse Committers
Version: Neon.3 Release (4.6.3)
Build id: 20170314-1500

I'm running on MacOSX High Sierra.

It's probably something very simple.

Comment: Maybe the dependencies in `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF` are bound to a very specific version and your target platform is the running platform (so no dependency can be resolved). By the way, also Neon is pretty old. The current version is Eclipse 2018-09.

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar problem every time I upgrade my eclipse installation.

For me the problem can be solved by adjusting the `Target platform` (can be found in the settings - just search for it) to match the currently running one. For that in most cases I simply add a target platform with default configuration and set that one active.

After a rebuild (normally performed automatically) all those errors are gone.

Comment: Thanks that worked.  It's bizarre.  I changed it from (old) "Running Platform" to (new) "Running Platform".  The only difference is that the original "Running Platform" has a plugin icon whereas the new (working) one has an Eclipse icon.

Comment: @John Tang Boyland Yeah that's the same on my system all the time. However the old "Running Platform" usually is broken. Don't know why but recreating it that way fixes it...